# How is this SQL query result being processed by this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, odbc

Here is the function:

```
function maxBatch(reqs) {
  reqs = reqs.map(b => ({
    id: b['BTCH#BD'],
    type: b['BTYPEBD']
  }));
  return reqs.reduce((max, o) => parseInt(o['BTCH#BD'], 10) > parseInt(max['BTCH#BD'], 10) ? o : max, reqs[0]);
}
```

A querySync select statement result is sent as an argument to this function. I understand that the reqs array is being remade into a new array with each element in the array with the properties 'BTCH#BD' and 'BTYPEBD' and their respective values being reorganized into id: value1 and type: value2. Where I am confused is the return statement.

I haven't had too much experience with .reduce(), but googling it online tells me that it basically processes each element in the array into a single value according to the conditions. It looks like the reduce() method is comparing the size between original and max arguments and if original is bigger it takes original, while if max is equal to or bigger it takes the max value and the very first element in the reqs array.

For reference I console.logged the value of the resulting returned object and it returned:

```
maxObj: 56978, OP2.
```

The original array that was sent was

```
rows: [{"BTCH#BD":56978,"BTYPEBD":"OP2"},
{"BTCH#BD":56978,"BTYPEBD":"OP2"},
{"BTCH#BD":56978,"BTYPEBD":"OP2"},
{"BTCH#BD":56978,"BTYPEBD":"OP2"},
{"BTCH#BD":56978,"BTYPEBD":"OP2"}]
```

Comment: What SQL Query? Read the docs for reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce and ternary operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the function is returning the correct value, but only because they are all the same and you're beginning with a valid value.

the map is taking that original array and returning a new array like this

`[{ id: 56978, type: 'OP2' }]`

You're then iterating through that new array and returning the max value by comparing the BTCH#BD key on those objects, which no longer exists after the map function. You should be comparing the 'id' key if you want to compare the BTCH#BD values.

The reduce function takes two parameters: the callback function and an optional initial value. The initial value is being set to `reqs[0]`, which is a valid value Your callback function checks if `undefined > undefined` and since it's not, it returns the initial value.

written in a slightly more readable way it looks like this:

```
    return reqs.reduce((max, o) => {
        if (parseInt(o.id, 10) > parseInt(max.id, 10)) {
            return o;
        }
        return max;
    }, reqs[0]);
```

Comment: edit: sorry. I didn't see you were the original poster!

It doesn't seem necessary in this case but I just figured I'd keep it as close to the original as possible to solve the issue at hand